# Jquery hidden invalid token

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

When I try to run my page there is a hidden syntax error on my scripts.

I am using magnific ajax to popup another html as a modal

```
<a href= "artpage.php" class="box">
    <img class="displayer" src = "temps/uploads/one.jpg">
</a>
```

the modal script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').magnificpopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        closeOnBgClick: 'false',
        overflowY: scroll
    });
});
```

artpage.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src = "scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img src="one.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i put

```
<script></script>
```

just above the

```
</body>
```

it always gives me a syntax error even if there is nothing inside the script and if i put a script in it it won't work. In the console log  source it displays an 'x' at the end of the script which calls a unexpected token even if there is nothing.

the error console.log gives me

```
VM98:17 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at DOMEval (jquery-3.2.1.js:82)
at domManip (jquery-3.2.1.js:5788)
at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery-3.2.1.js:5924)
at t.appendContent (jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4)
at Object.success (jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4)
at fire (jquery-3.2.1.js:3317)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.js:3447)
at done (jquery-3.2.1.js:9272)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.js:9514)
```

vm98:17 leads me to the end of the script with an x that isn't there.

EDIT: typo

EDIT2: given the console.log error

Comment: Should there be spaces after your tag attributes?

Comment: Can you add your error look like

Comment: @SamuelAsor That doesn't really matter.

Comment: I've written the console.log error